# Changing the NavigationBar's height in 'viewDidAppear' and 'viewDidLoad', Why is it different？

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I just want to reduce the height of the NavigaitonBar.

I put the following code in **ViewDidLoad** then I ran the project. The height changed in a moment, but it was restored to the default height shortly .

```
CGRect navRect  = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
navRect.size.height = 30;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = navRect;
```

And I tried to put these code in **viewWillAppear**, the same issue happened again!

But in **viewDidAppear**, it works properly, the height was changed.

I always add some barButtonItem in viewDidLoad. It illustrates that the NavigationController has been successfully initialized in viewDidLoad,but why can't the height be changed?

This confused me for a long time.

Thanks!

Comment: paste your code in -viewDidLayoutSubview

Comment: @RoNiT I have no code here. And almost all of the code above I have given.

Comment: I mean, change `heightConstraint` in -viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: @RoNiT The order of launching is 'viewDidLoad' -> 'viewDidLayoutSubviews' -> 'viewWillAppear' -> 'viewDidAppear', I want to know why the code of changing height only works in viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 3):

Since Auto Layout was added the lifecycle of views also was changed.
All geometric modifications of subviews in view should be done in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.
As you can see from the name of this method it means that all subviews will have placed properly at the moment when this method will be called.

Comment: I have tried  using pure code and storyboard, It makes no sense, The code that I given only works properly in viewDidAppear, this is too weird.

Answer (score 1):

if your table needs to load data every time with new Data then it should be under viewWillAppear
Otherwise, if the table needs to be reload by a single Data which doesn't vary or there is not any editing operation performed on Data , you should use viewDidload